# PSQL Is it possible to capture data returned by a function for audit?

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, audit, set-returning-functions

So, I have a database in place that I am managing and tasked with expanding. We use it to support server patching, and when I took over the project there is currently nothing in place in the database side to audit the actions, functions, etc that are firing throughout the day. For obvious reasons my management team is not okay with this.

I'm aware that the UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT can all be audited easily enough with triggers, but the core of the patching system requires communication with a different server that handles the actual patching. The database uses a function set up to return data to the other server, looks something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION patching.return_patch_info()
RETURNS table (
server_name text,
patch_time timestamp,
reboot_time timestamp,
env text
)
AS $$
    DECLARE
        <variables declared>
    BEGIN
        PERFORM dblink_connect('my_conn','FDW_connect');

        RETURN QUERY
            SELECT
                patching.server_info.name AS server_name,
                patching.server_info.patch_time AS patch_time,
                patching.server_info.reboot_time AS reboot_time,
                patching.server_info.env AS environment
            FROM patching.server_info
            WHERE <qualifying statements>;

        PERFORM dblink_disconnect('my_conn');
    END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My question is, how do I audit what data is returned by this function? Am I able to easily capture the returned data and store it in another table for auditing purposes? All my searching on google has sort of come up with nothing and I can't download and use any 3rd party software. This has to be developed and maintained in house.

Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: Auditing the statements executed can be done with the log file. If you want to record the result set, there is no other way than to rewrite the function to do that.

Comment: Yes, my management is really wanting me to capture the result set. So what's the best way to edit the function? Duplicate the query with a CREATE TABLE AS statement to put the results into a new table directly?

Comment: Duplicating the query is maybe not so great. You could read the result set row by row with a cursor and audit and return each row.